# setup.py in python showing 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named' altough it exists and is there

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I have a small app in the structure folder **'base'** and the child folder as **base>start**. To package it I have a **setup.py** in folder base. The code of which is

```
setup(name='bashed',
      version='0.1.0',
      packages=find_packages(),
      #packages=[start],
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'bashed = start.__main__:main'
          ]
      },
      )
```

In the child folder, '**start**', I have a file called **__main__.py** with a '**main**' method.

When I run the command

> python setup.py install

followed by

> bashed

I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'start'

However when I run the command

> python setup.py develop

followed by

> bashed

The function '**main**' in '**start.__main__.py**' is executed.

I have tried using
packages=find_packages()
as well as 
packages=[start]
in the setup.py but did not work

The content of setup.py includes

```
setup(name='bashed',
      version='0.1.0',
      packages=find_packages(),
      #packages=[start],
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'bashed = start.__main__:main'
          ]
      },
      )
```

The content of start.**main**.py is below

```
def main():
    print("This is the main routine.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `packages=['start']` (note the single quotes) or if you use `packages=find_packages()` make sure you have a `start/__init__.py` file.